# Errors in MVC solution, but builds and works anyway! How can I stop the errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, devexpress, visual-studio-2012

Any suggestions would be fantastic.

Basically I'm getting all sorts of errors [image: errors].

[image: moreerrors]

As you can see, it looks like the references simply cannot be found etc. All of the assemblies are being referenced correctly, confirmed by the fact that the solution builds and the website works fine. (Models, partial views et al). I just want to get rid of the errors! Its stopping any kind of intellisense, making the site creation that much slower.

Has anybody experienced similar issues before? Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 1):

Try to Clean solution and rebuild it.

Comment: which frameworks are installed on your pc? example: 4.0 and 3.5 SP1?

Comment: Yes, both. All the latest up to date versions. Restarted Visual Studio many times as well.

Comment: it might be a framework conflict.  you can use a dotnetfx cleanup tool and leave only 4.0.

Comment: another option is to refresh references. On Solution explorer click "all files" on the tree below remove/add one by one all the references